# Tweetsharp doesn't send tweet or throw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, tweetsharp

I want to send a tweet via the Twitter API. The bot connects but it simply does not do anything.
I've tried to send direct messages or simply read tweets but nothing happens.
The app does not execute the code in the `_twitterService.SendTweet()` Method. No exceptions are thrown.

```
    private const string ApiKey = "*************";

    private const string ApiSecretKey = "*********************";

    private const string AccessToken = "**************-****************";

    private const string AccessTokenSecret = "*********************";

    private static readonly TwitterService _twitterService = new TwitterService(ApiKey, ApiSecretKey, AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - Start");
        SendTweet();
    }

    public static void SendTweet()
    {
        var result = _twitterService.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions { Status = "Hello World" }, (tweet, response) =>
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - Tweet sent");
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - ERROR - {response.Error.Message}");
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you see `Tweet sent` output on console? How do you check if tweet it posted successfully or not?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the app does not execute the code in _twitterService.SendTweet()"? If you put a breakpoint on the first line in your Main method (Console.Writeline), and start debugging, and step line by line what happens? If it does go into the SendTweet method, what is the value of result after that first line executes?

Comment: The result is null. And there is no console output either.